# WCF jQuery or ScriptManager

Tags: wcf

I have an ASP.net 3.5 web application

I have a Firefox browser plugin that is use to connect and communicate with a scanner attached to a client computer.

I need to send data from the client computer (retrieved form the scanner) to the remote SQL database through WCF web service So far I have tested the following.

I was able to create a WCF service (RESTful) and using JSON to wire data to and from
on the client side.

I created a prototype using **jQuery** and Serializied my object using JSON2.js `stringify()` and sent it to the remote server.  Similarly, I can GET (retrieve) my custom object back in to the client code (JavaScript)

Questions
a) Is this a correct approach? Do you think instead of using jQuery/JSON (`ajax()` with POST) it is advisable to use `ScriptManager` along with AJAX enabled WCF.

b) Currently, the plugin sends data as a `JavaScript` object which I have to **reformat** so it can be wired back to the web service. WCF service accept one input object and browser plugin(add-on) data that is returned as JavaScript object has different property names so I have to recreate another object so it can be stringified in the format web service accept it

**can I pass object retrieved from scanner (inside JavaScript) directly and deserialize it on the server side (WCF) Level?**

It looks like WCF is doing it automatically for me but I have to reformat the object on the client. I want to avoid it and see it can be send directly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the requirement. The JQuery option will be a lot faster. If you don't have complex service requirements that may require 2 way connections, or guaranteed connections - then JQuery is fine.